# anonymous function with multiple parameters

Tags: r

don't ask if my example is reasonable, maybe there are examples how to circumvent my question, but maybe it is not possible to pass more than one parameters to an anonymous function that should be applied groupwise to a data.frame

I have a data.frame

```
w <- c("A", "B")
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c(3,4)

df <- data.frame(w,x,y)
```

Now I want to apply a function to each group (defined by column w) that creates column z by multiplying the columns x and y like

df$z <-    ...(list(df$x, df$y), df$w, FUN=function(x,y) {x * y}

Actually, I'm not asking for a concrete answer for the multiplication, I'm asking for the syntax how to apply two or more parameters to an anonymous function.

I changed the example due to the correct comment from Joshua, that tapply will not work with a list.

Any hints appreciated

Tom

Comment: I won't ask if it's reasonable.  I'll tell you it isn't. :) `tapply` works for an atomic `X` (see `?tapply`).  Lists are not atomic.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but my question remains, how can I apply multiple parameters to an anonymous function within a data.frame

Comment: @TomMartens with grouping?

Comment: not necessarily with grouping, but I want to pass to parameters to an anonymous function

Comment: you might be looking for `mapply` ?

Comment: If grouping isn't necessary, I agree with @BenBolker, you're probably looking for `mapply`.

Comment: To chime in, most of the `*apply` functions let you supply additional arguments to the specified function. Check the help pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this would be one way:

```
do.call(mapply, c(function(x, y) x * y, df[-1]))
# [1] 3 8
```

The number of columns in your `data.frame` (after removing, say, an ID column) will have to match the number of arguments in the anonymous function.

Or if you want to specify the columns explicitly:

```
mapply(function(x,y) x * y, df$x, df$y)
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, mapply works. It also works without do.call: df$z <- mapply(FUN=function(x, y) {x * y}, x=df$x, y=df$y)

Comment: Yeah, `do.call` would just be a matter of convenience if you know the number of columns match the number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Not understand why using anonymous user-defined functions when you can use built-in functions as `Reduce` or `apply` with either `*` or `prod`. Considering this data.frame:

```
  w x y
1 A 1 3
2 B 2 4
3 A 3 6
4 A 4 1
5 B 5 2

> Reduce("*", df[,-1])
[1]  3  8 18  4 10

> apply(df[,-1], 1, prod)
[1]  3  8 18  4 10
```

Comment: Jilber, thanks for your answer, but in this solution, there is no anonymous function, my question is more about the anonymous function than using prod - sorry.